# getting bad accuracy of classification using keras sequential model

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

i'm trying to build a cnn model using keras sequential model and tensorflow in order to classify images into two classes cats and dogs. the images are downloaded from kaggle. I've stored the images in csv files as training and testing databases. the problem is that i'm getting very bad accuracy results. here's a part of my code.

I've tried tuning my model using vgg16 but still bad accuracy. i increased the number of epochs but still no improvement

```
data_train = pd.read_csv('class_training_pixels.csv')
data_test = pd.read_csv('class_test_pixels.csv')
train_X, valid_X, train_label, valid_label = train_test_split(train_X, train_Y_one_hot, test_size=0.2, random_state=13)
train_X.shape,valid_X.shape,train_label.shape,valid_label.shape
test_X, valid2_X, test_label, valid2_label = train_test_split(test_X, test_Y_one_hot, test_size=0, random_state=13)
batch_size = 20
epochs = 10
num_classes = 2
from keras import backend
from keras import backend
backend.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
fashion_model = Sequential()
fashion_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='linear',padding='same',input_shape=(w,h,1)))
fashion_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
fashion_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
fashion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))
fashion_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
fashion_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
fashion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
fashion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))
fashion_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
fashion_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
fashion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
fashion_model.add(Dropout(0.4))
fashion_model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
fashion_model.add(Dense(128, activation='linear'))
fashion_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
fashion_model.add(Dropout(0.3))
fashion_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
fashion_model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=.00001),metrics=['accuracy'])
fashion_model.summary()
fashion_train = fashion_model.fit(train_X, train_label, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1,validation_data=(valid_X, valid_label))
val_loss, val_acc = fashion_model.evaluate(test_X, test_Y_one_hot, verbose=0)
print(val_acc, val_loss)
predicted_classes = fashion_model.predict_classes(x_test)
print(predicted_classes)
```

here's the results of the last epoch

```
Epoch 10/10

20/99 [=====>........................] - ETA: 19s - loss: 0.6835 - acc: 0.5500
40/99 [===========>..................] - ETA: 14s - loss: 0.7079 - acc: 0.4250
60/99 [=================>............] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.7014 - acc: 0.4833 
80/99 [=======================>......] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.6957 - acc: 0.5125
99/99 [==============================] - 26s 267ms/step - loss: 0.6955 - acc: 0.5051 - val_loss: 0.6943 - val_acc: 0.4400
```

and here's the accuracy and loss respectively:
0.5 0.6918725371360779

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your activations ->
This layer is a Conv2D with a `linear` activation function :

```
fashion_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
```

and this add an other activation function whitch is `LeakyRelu` :

```
fashion_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
```

You have to choose between one or the other.
I will advise you to delete the `LeakyRelu` layers and change the activation functions inside your Conv2D layers by `activation='relu'`.
Moreover i think you can increase your learning rate, and use `lr = 1e-3` or `lr = 1e-4`.

## More ideas

- `Dropout` is a good regularization layer in case of overfitting, whitch is not the problem here, start by build a model without it and add it later if needed.
- Don't think that `GlobalAveragePooling2D()` is a good idea here, try to replace it with a `Flatten()` layer.
- Try to increase the batch_size if you have a big dataset
- Normalize your images can help converge better and faster so try to scale your input array with `train_x = train_x / 255.0`

With all the ideas previously stated, i managed to reach a way better accuracy by just modifying your implementation.

Comment: thank you sir, but I still get bad accuracy, could there be any other problem?

Comment: thank you sir, i applied your suggestions and got the following: Epoch 10/10

20/99 [=====>........................] - ETA: 19s - loss: 0.5516 - acc: 0.8750
40/99 [===========>..................] - ETA: 14s - loss: 0.5667 - acc: 0.8125
60/99 [=========>............] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.5683 - acc: 0.7917 
80/99 [==============>......] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5686 - acc: 0.7687
99/99 [=====================] - 26s 264ms/step - loss: 0.5862 - acc: 0.7020 - val_loss: 0.6798 - val_acc: 0.6400, there is an improvement in the training acc, but i still get 0.55 and 0.71 as val acc and val loss

Comment: i wonder if the results are clear though, i'm grateful for all the help

Comment: Could you update your answers with those logs ? It will be more clear
And with the new model that you are running too, please !

Comment: You said 'but i still get 0.55 and 0.71 as val acc and val loss' but the logs say that it's better than that :' val_loss: 0.6798 - val_acc: 0.6400'
I added an other point in my answer that you can try

Comment: At the bottom of your post you should have an 'edit' button that you can use in order to add informations to your question.

Comment: I updated the following in my code: changed activation to 'relu', deleted LeakyRelu layers, removed  'dropout' layers, and changed GlobalAveragePooling2D() to Flatten().I also changed the activation of the output layer from softmax to sigmoid and used binary_crossentropy in compiling.I used lr of 0.001.I also normalized the images.I obtained the following training history acc [0.520, 0.467, 0.5, 0.5241, 0.5201, 0.633, 0.689, 0.7258, 0.842, 0.931, 0.9677, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],which seems good, but still the val acc and val loss are 0.5166 & 2.670

Comment: How did you get those val acc and val loss results ? Because in your precedent comment your print the last epoch with a way better val_acc :' val_acc: 0.6400'

Comment: I used a batch size of 10 with 20 epochs. and I used to train the network on 99 instances and validate it using 25 ones, then test it on 30. now I removed the validation, i'm using all 124 instances for training and 30 for testing

Comment: OK the problem is pretty clear so, 124 images for a classification CNN is far from being enough, go get more data, if you taked it from kaggle you should have thousand of exemples !

Comment: yeah there are more, but I thought of trying a small database, so i'd better add more examples to each class. I'm very grateful sir

Comment: Glad to have helped you ! If It was the help you were looking for, could you upvote and accept the answer ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For your conv layers you should be using ReLU as your activation function, also, if it is two classes, you should be using sigmoid in your output layer and binary_crossentropy when compiling.

Comment: based off of the name "fashion_model" im guessing you based this off of an existing notebook for Fashion MNIST, that's multi-class classification, not binary.

Comment: thank you sir, I made the modifications you've recommended but I still unfortunately get bad accuracy

Answer (score 0):

You just have two classes right, Maybe you have a class imbalance problem which might be the reason for your less accuracy and try with `Flatten()` when you convert to the one dimensional matrix

Comment: I balanced my classes before using them. I made sure I had the same number of examples in each class. you mean use flatten instead of reshaping?